# How to make a ranking list by elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ranking

I want to make a ranking list in order to show the ranking of every users when a game is finished.
This is fields of data:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "userId":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "score":{
        "type": "double"
      },
      "timeStamp":{
        "type": "date"  
      }                 
    }  
  }
}
```

Every users can get a score after gaming, and insert a doc into es.We can get the total score in specified period of a user by:

```
GET integral_stream/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "userId": "1"
          }, 
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2023-07-31T05:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2023-08-07T04:59:59.999Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10, 
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_score": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the problem: although I can count the buckets which total_score is gte someones total_score to get he's ranking, but how can I **get several users' ranking by once search**?

If I can not do this, should I change the structure of data, even give up using es to make the ranking list?

Answer (score 0):

In any kind of scenario, to calculate the exact ranking of people you need to first calculate score of **every person**, that you don't have in Elastic. So I think better approach is to store total score of each person.

If you want to go with you approach you can simply increase the size of agg and get all users scores and find the rank in your application. This obviously won't work if you have many users as size is limited in Elastic. For that you can take a look at [composite agg](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html).